# Tighter logarithmic inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

There is a well-known lower bound for
$$
x\log{1+x\over x}\geq {x\over1+x}
$$
for $x\geq0$. I know a tighter lower bound on the same domain
$$
x\log{1+x\over x}\geq{2x\over1+2x}\geq {x\over1+x}.
$$
It can be proved by Jensen's inequality.
Do you know something tighter?

Comment: You may have to define what sort of functions you want to use in the RHS / bound.  For e.g. are you seeking best approximations using a ratio of polynomials or just ratio of linear terms? Otherwise of course one trivially has $f \ge g \implies f \ge (f+g)/2$ as an example to generate any number of successively tighter bounds from any starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If *any* tighter lower bound will suffice, here you go with a ratio of quadratics:
$$x \log \frac{x+1}x \ge \frac{3 x \,(2x+1)}{6x^2+6x+1} \ge \frac{2x}{2x+1}$$

Proving the rightmost inequality is easy with cross multiplication to get $\iff x \ge 0$.  For the left inequality, you need to show for $x > 0$,
$$ f(x)= \log \left(1+\tfrac1x \right) - \frac{6x+3}{6x^2+6x+1} \ge 0$$
which is evident from $\displaystyle f'(x) = -\frac1{x(x+1)(6x^2+6x+1)^2} < 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

---

P.S. You can keep getting better approximations using larger polynomials $\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ - one way is to ensure that this matches in limits ($x \to 0, x \to \infty$) with your LHS, then get as many terms of the Taylor series (or as $x \to \infty$) to match as you want.  You may also want to google or read up on Pade approximants.